# How to prove that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{7}$ is irrational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

**Prove that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{7}$ is irrational using contradiction**.

I would appreciate if you could go over the proof in as much detail as possible. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the rational root theorem?

Comment: Have you seen the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational?

Comment: "I would appreciate if you could go over the proof in as much detail as possible". So where is the proof then?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Unfortunately not.

Comment: @RossMillikan I have seen the proof for $ \sqrt{2} $, and I wonder whether I'd have to prove that first in order for this proof to be complete. Meaning, whether I must prove that $ \sqrt{2} $ is irrational before I've proved this one.

Comment: @nocomment:  see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), and note that $\sqrt2+\sqrt7$ is a root of $x^4-18x^2+25$

Comment: There are several approaches.  The linked question has a general proof.  You would usually start with $\sqrt 2$, then note the same works for any square root of a prime, then go on.  The rational root theorem is another way-find a polynomial that $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 7$ satisfies and show it has no rational roots.

Comment: Note that $(\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{2})=7-2=5$. Assume $\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{2}$ is rational. Then so is $\frac{5}{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{2}$. If both $\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{2}$ are rational, then so is their sum (and difference) implying that $2\sqrt{7}$ is rational. You should be able to readily show that is impossible, so the assumption that $\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{2}$ is rational must be incorrect.